# I'm having an error in mysql like command ="SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE Course LIKE ('%'+ ? + '%')

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to have a search function in my system so I use textbox and button to display data in gridview.

But I don't know what is the right syntax to use like command. This syntax doesn't show any data in gridview.

```
"SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE Course LIKE ('%'+ ? + '%')"
```

I'm using sql data source on gridview.

Comment: And what is supposed to find that query?

Comment: It is supposed to find all the subjects with that course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  mysql you don't have  +  for string  concatenation

so you should use concat (assuming  you pass a param for ?)

```
"SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE Course LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%');"
```

or procedural code

```
 "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE Course LIKE '%'" + SomeText+ "%';"
```

or like suggested by vbnet3d for VB.Net

```
"SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE Course LIKE '%" & SomeText & "%'"
```

Comment: Or `"SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE Course LIKE '%" & SomeText & "%'"` for VB.Net

Comment: @vbnet3d   . thanks   answer  updated with your suggestion  and refer

Comment: Said to avoid comments like thanks, but I want to say thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Gab   . it is true to say that should be avoided but are always nice

Answer (score 1):

I think you need it to be "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE Course LIKE '%SomeText%'"

Having the percent signs on both sides of SomeText indicates to MySql than any text can come before SomeText and any text can come after it.

So this query would return all rows from the `subjects` table where the `course` field contained "SomeText" somewhere in the field.